# confusing javascript Math.cos function return value

Tags: javascript

My code is shown below

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

var v=Math.cos(45);
var v1=Math.sin(45);


alert(v);
alert(v1);
</script>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect v, v1 value are 1, 1
but it show as 0.525 0.850

Comment: Why do you expect sin(45) and cos(45) to be 1?

Comment: The argument is in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those function expects arguments passed as radians, not degrees. Try this:

```
var v=Math.cos(45 * Math.PI/180);
var v1=Math.sin(45 * Math.PI/180);
```

Note that the result you're after is 0.707, not 1.

Comment: Even if the arguments were in degrees, sin(45) and cos(45) would be 0.7071..., not 1. OP just has his math terribly wrong.

Comment: I forgot, 1 is for Math.tan()